# Solving a second-order boundary value equation on a non-uniform mesh

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I have an equation of the form

`y'' + a(x) y' + b(x) y = f(x)
y(0) = y(1) = 1`

where `x` is non-uniformly spaced.

How can I solve this type of second-order boundary value problem in python?

Comment: Would you know where to start if the mesh was uniform? If you don't have a background in numerical methods, it might be better to point you to an online learning resource.

Comment: Alternatively, would you know how to solve this if it were an initial value problem with `y(0) = 1`, `y'(0) = s` for some constant `s`? In which case you want to look up the [shooting method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method).

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for the family of functions [ y<sub>x</sub>`(t)` ] where `t` is the variable on which you derive `y`?

Are your boundary conditions true for all x?

You might want to look at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html